# Detect TreeView Node-Image Click

Tags: vb6, treeview

I have a TreeView in VB6, when a Node's Image (+ or -) is clicked the Node expands then immediately collapses, or vice versa. I have a TreeView Click method which expands/collapses a Node when it is clicked (simplified version shown below)

```
Private Sub MyTreeView_Click()

    Dim selectedNode As Node
    Dim nodeType As String

    Set selectedNode = MList2.SelectedItem
    If selectedNode Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    nodeType = selectedNode.Key

    If nodeType = "MyNodeType" Then

        'Collapse Node if it's already expanded, otherwise expand it.
        If selectedNode .Expanded Then
            selectedNode .Expanded = False
        Else
            'Do some processing

            selectedNode .Expanded = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This works fine if the text part of the Node is clicked. However if the Image part of the Node is clicked the Node is expanded/collapsed before this EventHandler is reached, resulting in the Node immediately returning to its original state when it does hit this EventHandler. The first expand/collapse of the Node seems to occur on MouseDown on the Node Image.

Does anyone know how I can prevent the Node from been expanded/collapsed before hitting this EventHandler when the Node Image is clicked?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try handling the collapse/expand messages and drop them, allowing your code to set it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the TreeView's `Collapse` and `Expand` events to set a Boolean variable that indicates your procedure shouldn't run. EG:

```
Dim bNodeImageClicked As Boolean

Private Sub MyTreeView_Collapse(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)
    bNodeImageClicked = True
End Sub

Private Sub MyTreeView_Expand(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)
    bNodeImageClicked = True
End Sub

Private Sub MyTreeView_Click()
    If bNodeImageClicked Then
        bNodeImageClicked = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Your code...
End Sub
```